# Can I retrieve all events some user was invited?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can retrieve every event I'm attending (or maybe) with `https://graph.facebook.com/me/events`. Is it possible to do the same but for every event I was invited and didn't replied yet?